# How to parse an ISO date with LocalDateTime.parse(...)

Tags: java, datetime, java-time, iso, localdatetime

I want to parse a date string like `2011-11-30` like this:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2011-11-30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
```

But I get the following exception:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2011-11-30' could not be parsed:
Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor
```

If I pass a date **and** time string everything works as expected:

```
LocalDateTime.parse("2011-11-30T23:59:59", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE_TIME)
```

How can I parse a date like `2011-11-30` to a LocalDateTime (with a default time)?

Comment: Well, use LocalDate.parse(), and then change it to a LocalDateTime by specifying which time you want.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @JB Nizet suggested, the following works

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2011-11-30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.atTime(23, 59, 59);
System.out.println(localDateTime); // 2011-11-30T23:59:59
```

> How can I parse a date like 2011-11-30 to a LocalDateTime (with a default time)?

1. Parse it first in a `LocalDate`
2. Use `LocalDateTime` `atTime()` method to set your default time

Note: Use of `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE` is superfluous for `parse()`, see [API LocalDate#parse()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-)

Answer (score 4):

The sample below use some magic numbers, wich should be avoid ([What is a magic number, and why is it bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad)).

Instead of using the method atTime(hour, minute, second),

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2011-11-30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = localDate.atTime(23, 59, 59);
```

you can use the LocalTime constants, such as [LocalTime.MAX](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MAX),  (23:59:59), [LocalTime.MIN](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIN) (00:00:00), [LocalTime.MIDNIGHT](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#MIDNIGHT) (23:59:59) or [LocalTime.NOON](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#NOON) (12:00:00)

```
    LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse("2011-11-30", DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE);
    LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.MIN);
```

It is better for maintainability and cross-reference.

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 2):

## Why I've written this answer despite existing answers

Unfortunately, all of the existing answers are only partially correct. They lack the following important aspects of the modern date-time API:

1. Using ISO format while parsing a date string
2. How to apply the current time to an instance of `LocalDateTime` to get a new instance of `LocalDateTime` with the current time

**Question posted by OP:**

> How can I parse a date like 2011-11-30 to a LocalDateTime (with a
> default time)?

## Answer

There are two problems with your approach:

1. Since you are parsing a date string, you should have used `LocalDate#parse` instead of `LocalDateTime#parse`.
2. Since your date string is already in the ISO pattern, you need not specify this pattern using `DateTimeFormatter` explicitly as `LocalDate.parse` uses this pattern by default.

   Apart from these two problems, you will need to use [`LocalDateTime#with`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#with-java.time.temporal.TemporalAdjuster-) to apply the current time to an instance of `LocalDateTime` to get a new instance of `LocalDateTime` with the current time.

   ```
   import java.time.LocalDate;
   import java.time.LocalDateTime;
   import java.time.LocalTime;

   public class Main {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // No need to specify DateTimeFormatter as the string is already in ISO format
           LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("2011-11-30");
           System.out.println(date);

           // Get LocalDateTime from LocalDate
           LocalDateTime ldt = date
                               .atStartOfDay()         //Convert to LocalDateTime with 00:00
                               .with(LocalTime.now()); //Adjust to current time

           System.out.println(ldt);
       }
   }
   ```

   **Output:**

   ```
   2011-11-30
   2011-11-30T11:53:39.103150
   ```

**Note:** Learn more about the modern date-time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.